# Compared with Vanilla JavaScript, does jQuery simplify selecting related nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my experience, jQuery simplifies DOM navigation immensely as when compared to using pure JavaScript.

Suppose I have two elements `#parentA` and `#parentB` and both these two elements have similar children nodes `.x` `.y` `.z`.

Often times, when I use JavaScript without jQuery, if I want to select `#parentA`'s `.x` I end up  accidentally selecting both `#parentA .x` as well as `#parentB.x`.

I suppose this is more of a backend developer's therapy session where I am just letting out my frustration with JS rather than asking a question.

The main reason why I am trying to avoid using jQuery is that I am trying to keep the website page weight as low as possible. What would the JavaScript equivalent be of the jQuery code I have below?

**HTML**

```
<h2>Colour 1</h2>
<div id="hairColor" class="color-palette">
  <ul>
    <li style="background: #fc4c4f;"></li>
    <li style="background: #4fa3fc;"></li>
    <li style="background: #ecd13f;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h2>Colour 2</h2>
<div id="skinColor" class="color-palette">
  <ul>
    <li style="background: #fc4c4f;"></li>
    <li style="background: #4fa3fc;"></li>
    <li style="background: #ecd13f;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.color-palette {
  background: #384047;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    li {
      display: block;
      height: 54px;
      width: 54px;
      border-radius: 60px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #222;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 5px 10px;
    }
    .selected {
      border: 7px solid #fff;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }  
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".color-palette").on("click", "li", function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  color = $(this).css("background-color");
});

// What would the equivalent code be using vanila JavaScript?
// var colors = document.querySelectorAll("#hairColor ul li");
```

Comment: "pure JavaScript" does not involve the DOM at all. You're talking about native browser APIs, which do not exist in (for example) Node.

Comment: So a rather wordy, yet thinly disguised request for *"please convert this jquery to vanilla javascript **for me**"*.    http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: It looks to me that your solution already works using the correct selectors `document.querySelectorAll("#parentA > x");`  Which part were you unable to find a replacement for?  It looks like you're only asking for the last 2 lines.

Comment: I think his issue is more with the siblings part, I remember when I started coding I didn't know how to convert the jQuery scope and siblings to vanilla and was always asking for help on that, and I'm talking about the `$(this).css` like stuff. `$(this)` was unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

To make that without something like jQuery, you'll need a few iterators (a for loop or something), is 100% doable and is not that hard but beware, is a larger piece of code.

What that code is doing is assigning the click event to the `color-palette` container and filtering by the target element to match the `LI`, if you want you can simplify it by just assigning the click to the `li` directly and check on the parent.

This is a starting point to replicate the same behavior:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.color-palette').forEach((palette) => {
    palette.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => {
        li.classList.remove('selected');
    })

        if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'li') {
        return;
    }
    
        e.target.classList.add('selected');
    })
})
```

This could be simplified a bit but is a draft and should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
let triggers = document.querySelectorAll('li')

triggers.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    [...triggers].map(x => x.classList.remove('selected'))
    el.classList.add('selected');
    let color = el.style.backgroundColor;
  })
})
```

First, you add eventlisteners to each li element, and when clicking on one, you create an array of the elements by using the spread `...` operator. Chain this array afterwards with the map operator to remove the selected class. And finally, you simply add the selected class to the element you've clicked.